# Asymptotics for simple series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $x > 0$, let

$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x}
$$

Can anyone find a simple equivalent of $f(x)$ when $x\to+\infty$ ?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}{{\rm e}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$
$x > 0$

> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + x}
> &=
> -\,{1 \over x}
> +
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + \ic\,x^{1/2}}\pars{n - \ic\,x^{1/2}}}
> =
> -\,{1 \over x}
> +
> {\Psi\pars{\ic\,x^{1/2}} - \Psi\pars{-\ic\,x^{1/2}} \over 2\ic\,x^{1/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\,{1 \over x}
> -
> \ic\,{1 \over 2x^{1/2}}\,\bracks{%
> {\Psi\pars{\ic\,x^{1/2}} - \Psi\pars{1 +\ic\,x^{1/2}}}
> +
> \pi\cot\pars{-\pi\ic\,x^{1/2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\,{1 \over x}
> -
> \ic\,{1 \over 2x^{1/2}}\,\bracks{%
> -\,{1 \over \ic\,x^{1/2}} + \ic\,{\pi \over \tanh\pars{\pi x^{1/2}}}}
> =
> {\pi \over 2x^{1/2}\tanh\pars{\pi x^{1/2}}} - {1 \over 2x}
> \end{align}

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + x}
=
{\pi \over 2x^{1/2}\tanh\pars{\pi x^{1/2}}} - {1 \over 2x}\,,
\qquad
x > 0
$$

$$
x \gg 1
\quad\imp\quad
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + x}
\sim
\color{#ff0000}{\large{\pi \over 2x^{1/2}}}
$$

Also, when $x \gg 1$, this asymptotic result can be found ( Riemann Sum ) as
$\pars{~N \gg 1~}$:
$$
\sim
N\int_{1/N}^{1}{{\rm d}\xi \over \xi^{2}N^{2} + x}
=
{1 \over x^{1/2}}\bracks{%
\overbrace{\arctan\pars{N \over x^{1/2}}}^{\sim\ \pi/2}
-
\overbrace{\arctan\pars{1 \over x^{1/2}}}^{\sim\ 0}}
\sim
{\pi \over 2x^{1/2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The summation over "n" leads to (-1+ x Sqrt[Pi] Coth[x Sqrt[Pi]]) / (2 x). If "x" goes to infinity, the limit is zero.

Sorry for not using LaTex; it is difficult for me since I am almost blind.

Comment: “leads to” : how ?

Comment: Excuse the question, it's just curiosity, but how being almost blind impairs you to write using LaTeX yet you can type in ASCII? After all, typing with LaTeX only requires to use a few symbols more, like the dollar sign, or slashes , etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I know my keyboard but I have never been able to format properly LaTex (few symbols : yes). So after some attempts, I decided to give up. Sorry for that

Comment: Well @ClaudeLeibovici, that really doesn't convince me but it's up to you. Anyway, your answer looks pretty "magical" and unbased: how is that done, using what...?